# Looking for invalidFields() with CakePHP

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I'm trying to find out how to get the actual message from my validate() array which contains all the rules to validate a submission within my model.

Basically I'm POSTing ajaxily and I'd like to return all of the error messages in the form that have failed validation, but it's sending them anyway even when they have passed validation.

So in my

`SubmissionsController` I'm doing this:

```
if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
    $formData = $this->Submission->invalidFields();
    $this->set(compact('formData'));
}
```

In my `Submission` model I have:

```
 var $validate = array(
    'title' => array(
        'title' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'required' => true,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => 'Please enter a title'
        ),
        'minLength' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', 5),
            'message' => 'Please make your title longer (e.g. IJL John F. Kennedy donated his presidential salary to charity)'
        ),
        'maxLength' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxLength', 300),
            'message' => 'Your title needs to be shorter'
        ),
    ),
    'description' => array(
        'shortDescription' => array(
            'rule' => array('shortDescription'),
            'message' => 'Your description needs to be longer'
        ),
        'longDescription' => array(
            'rule' => array('longDescription'),
            'message' => 'Your description needs to be shorter'
        ),
    ),
    'source' => array(
        'source' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'required' => true,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => 'Enter a valid source URL (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penguins)'
        ),
        'website' => array(
            'rule' => 'url',
            'message' => 'Enter a valid source URL (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penguins)'
        ),
    ),
    'category' => array(
        'category' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'required' => true,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => 'Please choose a category'
        )


    )
);
```

In my `Submissions/json/submit.ctp` file I have:

```
<?php
$fragment = $this->element('errors/flash_error');
$toReturn = array(
    'formData' => $formData
    );

echo json_encode($toReturn);
```

If I enter in a valid title or any other valid field, I still am getting back the error message instead of nothing.

Is there something I'm missing that `invalidFields()` needs in order to NOT return fields which HAVE passed validation?

EDIT:

As Leo suggested below, I wasn't calling save before `invalidFields()`

The correct code should be:

```
            if ($this->Submission->save($this->request->data)) {
                $formData = null;
            } else {
                $formData = $this->Submission->invalidFields();
            }
            $this->set(compact('formData'));
```

Comment: **This might helpful ...**


 
        
        


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854369/accessing-invalidfields-from-the-view

Comment: bob where are you doing the validation? You seem to be just calling invalidfields() without saving or validating?

Comment: @Leo wow man what the hell was I (not) thinking? Totally overlooked that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling invalidFields() without validation either by a save() call or validates()!

Comment: Any reason it'd be calling that validation method twice? http://i.imgur.com/ZBj5X.png is what I'm getting when I get my response using that same code (with the exception of the edit I made per your advice above)...

Comment: Had the same problem myself, some guy posted a patch I think in the core by essential doing an array_unique. If you google it I think its a bug

Comment: Turns out that `$this->Submission->save($this->request->data)` was calling save and so was `$this->Submission->invalidFields()`. Instead of your array_unique try doing this: `$this->Submission->set($this->request->data); if ($this->Submission->invalidFields($this->request->data)) { $formData = $this->Submission->validationErrors; } }`